# Etat HTTP 500 - Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, jdbctemplate

Dao:

```
public Vocabulary getItem(int categoryvocabularyid) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM vocabulary WHERE categoryvocabularyid = ?";
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql,new Object []{categoryvocabularyid}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Vocabulary>(Vocabulary.class));
}
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/public/vocabulary/{id}")
public String readedit(@PathVariable("id") int categoryvocabularyid, ModelMap modelMap){
    modelMap.addAttribute("vocal", vocaburalysDao.getItem(categoryvocabularyid));
    return "public.index.vocabulary.detail";
}
```

My view:

```
<c:forEach items="${cateVocal }" var="cateVocal">
        <div class="box-item">
            <a href="/exam/56">
                <!-- <div class="img"
                    style="background: url(/upload/2016/05/9106.jpg); background-size: cover;">
                    <p>0/54</p>
                </div> -->
                <!-- <div class="meter">
                    <span style="width: 0%"></span>
                </div> -->
                <h4>Chủ Đề: ${cateVocal.categoryVocaburalyName }</h4>
            </a><a class="learn" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/public/vocabulary/${cateVocal.id }">Học ngay</a>

        </div>
        </c:forEach>
```

I got an error, I do not know what causes it came from, 
Detail error

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 2
```

Pls hlep me.

Thank so much everyone

Comment: Have a look at the Javadoc for the method you are calling -- it explains what that exception means https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask a single item `Vocabulary` from your DB but actually it founds more than one, hence you receive the exception.

I saw that you're finding row by `categoryvocabularyid`, so here's solution:

1. If `categoryvocabularyid` is unique accross `Vocabulary` (this is very unlikely, I guess), then you have to put the unique index to the field in database, and remove the duplicate item
2. If not, you have to change the method return to `List<Vocabulary>`
   and use `queryForList` instead

Comment: how can I create rowMap for queryForList? example would be helpful.